# CreateFileMappingA() name paramater

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a program where you input a text file with words and a list of letters and it finds the longest word that it can make with those letters. I'm trying to make a code as fast as possible. My method of doing it is the most optimized I could think of, but the file reading using getline() is what is taking my program multiple hundreds of miliseconds. I have searched around and found out that I can map the data from my file into virtual memory of the process. This means I can dump the data into the program and work from it from there which wound make my program a lot faster.

I'm on windows so I'm using the winbase.h and windows.h libraries. I successfully made the CreateFileA() function so that it opens the file so that the CreateFileMappingA() function can make a handle for the MapViewOfFile() function.

`HANDLE mmh = CreateFileMappingA("words.txt", NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 4866048, 4863005, NULL);`

The last paramater is giving me a problem, the name paramater. on the microsoft dev center it says that the variable type is LPCSTR. It also mentions that if I put in NULL it won't have a name. Since I'm putting the return value in a variable I have no need for a name. I have tried putting in NULL and I got a compiler error stating:

`invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'HANDLE {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]`

I have tried putting in a LPCSTR type variable, it produced the same error.
I tried putting in a HANDLE and i got a compiler error stating:

```
invalid conversion from 'HANDLE {aka void*}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'HANDLE {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm unsure on what to do.

Comment: The first parameter is a file HANDLE, not a string or file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is what is wrong. It should be the file handle that was returned from CreateFileA not the name of the file.